# Склоняется ли название гос-ва Шри-Ланка?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Склоняется ли название государства Шри-Ланка?

Answer (score 1):

Справка Грамоты.ру говорит, что таки да, склоняется:

[Вопрос № 261459](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=261459)

Как склонять Шри-Ланка?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Вопрос № 289824](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=289824)

> Добрый день! Подскажите как правильно: из Шри-Ланки или со Шри-Ланки.
>   Имеется ввиду из государства?

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> Предлог *из* антонимичен предлогу *в*, а предлог *с* – предлогу *на*.
>   *Шри-Ланка* – государство, расположенное на острове. Поэтому выбор предлога зависит от значения: *на Шри-Ланку (со Шри-Ланки)* – на
>   остров (с острова), *в Шри-Ланку (из Шри-Ланки)* – в государство (из
>   государства).